# How do I prune all the '' from these strings generated from a CSV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, pruning

I've made this formula which turns a CSV into a dictionary:

```
def CSVtoDict(BDF, mode):
    saved={}
    with open('%s%s.csv' % (dataDir,BDF), mode='r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        for row in reader:
            if mode is 'prune' and row == '':
                break
            else:
                pass
            key = row[0]
            saved[key]=row[1:]
    return saved
```

I'm trying to make it so that when the mode is 'prune', any string from the CSV such as ['data1', 'data2', '', '', ''] is returned without any ''. But the break statement doesn't seem to work for some reason and things are returned as if there was no if else.

Also do you know what would be the pythonic way of doing this? I feel like this could be more efficient somehow...

Example line from the CSV:

Awareness,ASD,ASD2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: Can you show us a line or two of your input .csv file. I'm having trouble understanding your issue with single quotes. Are you saying the single quotes are in the file?

Comment: wait a minute, for this list: ['data1', 'data2', '', '', ''], is that the list result that you want? -> ['data1', 'data2']?

Comment: Miguel, check my answer and let me know please

Comment: Are there multiple blank entries per row, with multiple rows that can have blanks?

Comment: Could you edit your post with a small snippet straight from your CSV file? Something that would demonstrate what your file looks like? I seriously doubt that your actual csv file contains ['data1','data2','','',''].

Comment: @BoarGules A line from the csv would be:
Awareness,ASD,ASD2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

I want to prune all those ''

Comment: @DamianLattenero Yes it is, thanks :)

Comment: @TomSitter Every row has a lot of blank entries. But they're all at the end, none in the middle or start.

Comment: @MiguelAlberolaCano Okey perfect, I updated the answer, don't forget voting and accepting if that's what you were looking at :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you still have to loop through each entry, not just each row. Here is my solution:

```
# CSV contents
#  'data1', 'data2', 'data3', ''
#  'data4', 'data5', '' ''
#  'data6', '', '', ''

def CSVtoDict(BDF, mode):
    saved={}
    with open('%s%s.csv' % (dataDir,BDF), mode='r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        for row in reader:
            key = row[0]
            saved[key] = [r for r in row[1:] if not (r is '' and mode is 'prune')]
    return saved


# saved will equal
# {
#   'data1': ['data2', 'data3']
#   'data4': ['data5'], 
#   'data6': [], 
# }
```

Comment: Trying this out!

Comment: I've turned it into a function, it works! Thanks! :)

def CSVtoDict(BDF, mode):
 with open('%s%s.csv' % (dataDir,BDF), mode='r') as infile:
  reader = csv.reader(infile)
  saved = {}
  for row in reader:
   key = row[0]
   saved[key] = [r for r in row[1:] if not (r is '' and mode is 'prune')]
  return saved

Comment: Sorry if it's a mess, I don't know how to put it in a clearer format in the comments :(

Comment: You did it and it looks identical to mine! yay

Comment: No problem! Glad to help

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to filter out empty rows when `mode == 'prune'`, is that correct?  Or are you trying to stop as soon as you hit an empty row (which is what the `break` would achieve if your conditional was correct)?

The problem is that csv rows are returned as lists, not strings, i.e. a line in a csv file that looks like this:

```
a,b,1,2
```

will be returned as ['a','b','1','2'] when iterating through `reader`.  An empty row comes up as `[]`, not `''`.  If you want to check for an empty row, you can check for `len(row) == 0` instead.  Also, your `else: pass` doesn't really do anything so you can leave it out.  Result should be something like this:

```
for row in reader:
    if mode is 'prune' and len(row) == 0:
        break # or continue, if you want to proceed with the rest of the file
    key = row[0]
    saved[key]=row[1:]
```

If as another answer suggests, you're trying to prune out any row that has an empty field, then change `len(row) == 0` to `'' in row`.

Comment: I think the op want anything else :(

Comment: Thanks! I just want to prune the [] rows, not the entire row. Lemme try it out!

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you may want to use continue rather than break.  Break will take you out of the if/else statement, but continue will take you to the next iteration of the for loop.

Comment: Break interrupts loops, not if/else blocks. I think you have the right idea, just revise the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `row == ''` means the whole row is an empty string. YOu could substitute it with `'' in row` so:

```
if mode is 'prune' and '' in row:
```

Comment: I think the op want anything else :(

Comment: @MiguelAlberolaCano this will skip all the rows that contain an empty field somewhere, I also doubt that you might need that

Comment: I just want to prune the '', not the whole row. You're right

Answer (score 1):

wait a minute, is that what you want? if you want to remove all the `''` if `mode == "prune"` just do:

```
def CSVtoDict(BDF, mode):
    with open('%s%s.csv' % (dataDir,BDF), mode='r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        return [ row for row in reader if row != '' ] if (mode == "prune") else reader
```

Comment: I think that's it! But where would I put it within my function?

Comment: Whoopsie. I need a dictionary not a list. I'll try to see if I can adapt it. Thanks :)